# Взятие номера ячейки массива и присвоение его переменной

Tags: массивы

Массив `int A[20];`.
Как присвоить переменной `int k;` номер какой-либо ячейки?
`k = A[9];` - так мы присваиваем сам элемент из ячейки 8. А номер ее?

Comment: @art13, для начала сами себе ответьте на вопрос: "**что такое номер ячейки ?**". После этого заданный Вами вопрос видимо отпадет.

Comment: Номер ячейки и есть мое искомое)))))

Answer (score 2):

Присвоить номер ячейки `A[9]`

```
k=9
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я ищу в массиве самое маленькое значение и оно заранее неизвестно. При нахождении этого значения нужно запомнить его номер в массиве. И ваше выражение неправильно. При обращении к значению в массиве, отсчет идет от 0 а не от 1.

Comment: Мне интересно, как вы тогда ищите минимум, не обращаясь к элементам массива? Вроде как чтобы его найти, надо сравнить 2 числа и одно из них будет `A[index]`, значит и индекс минимума будет `index`.

Comment: Вы сначала определитесь с терминами. А поиск индекса минимального значения для массива `int amin = A[0], kmin = 0; for(int k=1; k<20;k++) if (A[k] < amin) {kmin = k; amin = A[k];}`

Comment: Код поиска у меня есть и все работает. Последний оратор помог. Не допер что нужно просто взять i и присвоить k. У меня шагает через i.